Golang regexp: get word which has opening & closing brackets
Need help with fetching word from a string.



STRING
WORD NEEDS TO BE FETCHED




"A = 2&& B = 2 && func1(A) && func2(B)"
func1, func2


"func1(A)"
func1


"B = 2 && func2(A)"
func2



I have tried with following regex
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\s+(?:\w+_\w+)`)
    var str = `func1(A)`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)
    }
}

But this regex provides empty result if there's no space before the word eg: for string "func1(A)".
This is working as expected when the word has a space before, for example for string "B = 2 && func2(A)" its giving func2 as expected.
Any help would be appreciated here

To find all the requested words you can use the following code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(^|\s)(\w+)\(.*?\)`)
    var str = `A = 2&& B = 2 && func1(A) && func2(B)
    func1(A)
    B = 2 && func2(A) func()`

    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match[2], "found")
    }
}

Explanation of the regex:
(^|\s) - The beginning of a line or a whitespace.
(\w+)  - Minimum 1 word character, with as many as possible.
\(     - The opening bracket literally.
.*?    - Any character, zero or few occurencies as possible.
\)     - The closing bracket literally.

You can test the code here

Following Code with Regex is providing the expected output. Removing the whitespace also from the output.
regexp.MustCompile(`\b\w+\(`)

Code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\b\w+\(`)
    var str = `func1(A) || B = 2 && func2(A)`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match[:len(match)-1], "found at index", i)
    }
}

Thanks Fenistil for the pointer.
Code can be tested here

Your code will find a string in func( which I don't know if you want or not. If you are about to find every function name, you must include the closing bracket as well in your regex (like in my solution)
